# Reading and Writing registry keys. C++ MFC MBCS.

Tags: c++, mfc, registry, mbcs

I would like to detect, and if possible read to a CString, a registry key starting with "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\blah\SetupPath".

I see the MSDN on RegOpenKeyEx function

```
LONG WINAPI RegOpenKeyEx(
  _In_        HKEY hKey,
  _In_opt_    LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
  _Reserved_  DWORD ulOptions,
  _In_        REGSAM samDesired,
  _Out_       PHKEY phkResult
);
```

So for this it looks like I need to setup a few things.

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
LPCTSTR lpSubKey = "SOFTWARE\blah\SetupPath";
```

And to see if the key exists just do

```
LONG res = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, 0, 0, 0);
if(res == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    // The key exists
```

Now if the key exists I want to read what is there, into a CString. I also see the RegQueryValueEx

```
LONG WINAPI RegQueryValueEx(
  _In_         HKEY hKey,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpValueName,
  _Reserved_   LPDWORD lpReserved,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpType,
  _Out_opt_    LPBYTE lpData,
  _Inout_opt_  LPDWORD lpcbData
);
```

It also looks like I need some setup before I call this function too.

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
lpSubKey = "SOFTWARE\blah\SetupPath";
LPDWORD type = null;
LPDWORD data = null;
```

Now I can call it

```
LONG res2 = RegValueQueryEX(hKey, lpSubKey, 0, type, data,0);
```

Then I think I can check to see the type and then cast to a string?

```
CString regVal;
if(res2 == ERROR_SUCCESS)
   if(type == REG_SZ)
      if(data != null)
          regVal = new CString((LPSTR)data);
```

Is this all correct? What might I be missing or need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not correct. Your main misunderstanding is how pointers work in C++. It's not enough to supply NULL for a pointer argument, you must supply a pointer to a variable so that the `RegOpenKeyEx` or `RegValueQueryEx` routine can return a value to that variable. You also seem to be misunderstanding how to assign to a `CString` (no need for `new`). Finally although it's not an error you don't need to do 'setup' you just pass the values directly to the function.

First open the key

```
HKEY key;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\blah", 0, 0, &key);
```

then get the value

```
DWORD type, size;
char data[99];
size = sizeof(data);
RegQueryValueEx(key, "SetupPath", 0, &type, (BYTE*)data, &size);
```

then assign the value to your `CString`

```
CString regval(data);
```

finally close the key

```
RegCloseKey(key);
```

No error checking in that code, you should add it. Also I'm assuming that any value you could get will fit in 99 bytes, that might not be true.

Note how I pass a pointer to the `key` variable, so that `RegOpenKeyEx` can return the key. I then use that key in the call to `RegValueQueryEx` and `RegCloseKey`. Same for the `type` and `size` variables. Also note that I've split the path between the calls to `RegOpenKeyEx` and `RegValueQueryEx`. I *think* that is correct.

Not 100% sure that is correct, I haven't tested it but should be quite a bit closer.

Comment: While this works, it ignore the `GetBuffer` /  `ReleaseBuffer` mechanism of `CString`. This pattern matches typical Win32 use; you get a buffer of a fixed size, call an API, and return the buffer to `CString` indicating how much of the buffer was used.

Comment: If work for me, but in my case only read access available:
`RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\blah", 0, KEY_READ, &key);`
If I use `0` instead `KEY_READ`, key will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this all correct? What might I be missing or need to do?

In addition to the answer by john I would suggest a few modifications:

1. pass `KEY_READ | KEY_QUERY_VALUE` as access rights mask to `RegOpenKeyEx` if you are only going to read the key.
2. `RegQueryValueEx` may return `ERROR_MORE_DATA` if the buffer size is too small. Unless you know the size of the data beforehand you might want to call it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

simple way to enabled javascript execution in internet explorer using the registry:

```
HKEY hKey;
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3"),
    NULL, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE,
    NULL, &hKey, NULL);

DWORD byte = 0x0;

RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"1400", NULL, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*)&byte, sizeof(byte));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```